# animating a simple css dropdown navbar on hovering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**UPDATED CODE AND QUESTION**

I have a simple navbar and I am trying to add some animation when hovering the dropdowns. But I cannot make it to work so I need some help to understand why it is not working.

Here is the html

```
<nav> 
<main-categories><a href="#void">News</a>
<sub-categories>
<a href="#">Europe</a>
<a href="#">Asia</a>
<a href="#">Africa</a>
<a href="#">Oceania</a>
<a href="#">North America</a>
<a href="#">South America</a>
</sub-categories></main-categories>
    
<main-categories><a href="#void">Politics</a>
<sub-categories>
<a href="#">Europe</a>
<a href="#">Asia</a>
<a href="#">Africa</a>
<a href="#">Oceania</a>
<a href="#">North America</a>
<a href="#">South America</a>
</sub-categories></main-categories>
    
<main-categories><a href="#void">Economy</a>
<sub-categories>
<a href="#">Europe</a>
<a href="#">Asia</a>
<a href="#">Africa</a>
<a href="#">Oceania</a>
<a href="#">North America</a>
<a href="#">South America</a>
</sub-categories></main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void">Health</a>
<sub-categories>
<a href="#">Europe</a>
<a href="#">Asia</a>
<a href="#">Africa</a>
<a href="#">Oceania</a>
<a href="#">North America</a>
<a href="#">South America</a>
</sub-categories></main-categories>

<main-categories><a href="#void">Education</a>
<sub-categories>
<a href="#">Europe</a>
<a href="#">Asia</a>
<a href="#">Africa</a>
<a href="#">Oceania</a>
<a href="#">North America</a>
<a href="#">South America</a>
</sub-categories></main-categories>
    
<main-categories><a href="#void">Culture</a></main-categories>

</nav>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}
body {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  font-family:'IBM Plex Serif',serif;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:400;
  color:#121212
}
a {
  color:#121212;
  text-decoration:none
}
a:hover {
  color:#E5633F
}
nav {
  grid-area:navi;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:3px solid #121212;
  background-color:inherit
}
nav {
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:8;
  width:100%
}
main-categories {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:inherit;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  height:42px;
  line-height:42px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0px 22px 0px 22px;
}
main-categories:hover {
  color:#E5633F
}
main-categories a {
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none
}   
main-categories a:hover {
  color:#E5633F
}
main-categories a:before{
  content: '▪ ';
}
sub-categories {
 display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;
  left:50%;
  transform:translatex(-50%);
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background-color:inherit
}
sub-categories a {
  display:block;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:0 36px 0 36px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-decoration:none;
  height:36px;
  line-height:36px;
  border-left:1px solid #121212;
  border-right:1px solid #121212;
  border-bottom:1px solid #121212
}   
sub-categories a:hover {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#121212
}
main-categories:hover sub-categories {
  display:block
}
sub-categories a:before{
  content: '';
}
```

And here is the animation effect I am trying to apply when hovering

```
sub-categories {
  animation:rotateMenu 400ms ease-in-out forwards
  transform-origin:top center
}
@keyframes rotateMenu {
    0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg)
    }
    70% {
    transform: rotateX(20deg) 
    }
    100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) 
    }
```

I also created a Codepen here to see it working
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/XWygWzY

Any idea why the effect is not working or how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you mean adding an animation when hovering on a menu ("news", "health", etc)? Define "opening" here.

Comment: Exactly, nice name by the way McQueen

Comment: Thank you, you have a nice name too! Your problem is easy you need to use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations). It depends on what animation you want to create. Anything on your mind? :-)

Comment: Why are you using `<main-categories>`? Why not just `<div>`? Any specific reason for that?

Comment: Because I want to make it easier to find it in css and to write less code

Comment: If you have no *specific reason* for that then use normal HTML elements like `<div>`, `<li>` and detect them using classes and IDs.

Comment: ok McQueen. Any idea why the animation is not working?

Comment: @theoneandnotonly Please add semicolon at the end of animation css like this : 
`sub-categories {
  animation: rotateMenu 400ms ease-in-out forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}`

Comment: Cedar Thakkar the animation worked but is no longer centered right under each main-category

Comment: Can you put it as an answer please so I can select your question as the correct one

Comment: theoneandnotonly, next time mention people (`@` then username) so they can see your response, I saw yours, but I guess I'm too late, anyway @KedarThakkar sounds like an answer :-)

Comment: @theoneandnotonly added as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a semicolon at the end of the CSS animation like this:

```css
sub-categories {
  animation: rotateMenu 400ms ease-in-out forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```