# css on hover add content to nth-of-type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this dropdown menu in two parts to understand it:

**main-categories:**

```
news
politics
economy
health
education
```

**sub-categories**

```
europe
asia
africa
oceania
North America
South America
```

The html (part of it), looks like this

```
<main-categories><a href="#void">Education</a>
<sub-categories>
<a href="#">Sweden</a>
<a href="#">Europe</a>
<a href="#">Asia</a>
<a href="#">Africa</a>
<a href="#">Oceania</a>
<a href="#">North America</a>
<a href="#">South America</a>
</sub-categories></main-categories>
```

What I need to do is:

Let´s take for example people select category Education, it is the number 5 in the list. When people is hovering the sub-categories of Education, I want to add content to the css of the Education main category like this:

```
main-categories:nth-of-type(5) 
sub-categories a:hover main-categories:nth-of-type(5):a 
{content:'• News • Education '}
```

So when people is hovering the sub-categories of Education, the word Education in main-categories (category number 5) changes to • News • Education

But it does not want to work

I have a Codepen with the full code of the dropdown menu here
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/XWygWzY

I can also add it here if you prefer but it is easy to understand the question with the posted code

Comment: Avoid putting content in CSS. Use a data attribute in your HTML then reference that in the CSS. Eg `<a data-hovered=''• News • Education ">` , CSS : `content: attr(data-hovered)` . That will also remove index dependency, you can then reorder the nav elements without worrying about CSS

Comment: Why are you using invalid HTML? `<main-categories>` and `<sub-categories>` do not exist, but `<div>`, `<ul>`, and `<li>` are valid. It may work because browsers render HTML liberally (basically any invalid element is a `<div>`), but it'll be hard to debug as you progress further along.

Comment: @zer00ne their justification for using those made-up tags from another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600623/animating-a-simple-css-dropdown-navbar-on-hovering#comment135056553_76600623: _"Because I want to make it easier to find it in css and to write less code"_ :rolleyes:

Comment: _"I can also add it here if you prefer"_ - we do; and easy to understand or not, has little to do with it. A proper [mre] of your issue always belongs directly into your question - content on 3rd-party platforms might change or disappear over time, making a question lose context for future readers.

Comment: Lol @CBroe yikes, taking the effort *not* to conform to standards for the sake of less code is not the direction someone should go if they want to learn any programming.

Comment: We are in 2023 and <main-categories> is absolutely valid in W3 standards. They are called custom-elements and are valid as long as they use hyphens and follow some other small rules

Comment: *"They are called custom-elements and are valid as long as they use hyphens and follow some other small rules."* Yes, [small rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements)  indeed .  Also, thank you for reminding me that it's 2023, I get confused at times and think that it's 10,000 BC 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `:hover` selector to the `main-categories` element:

```
main-categories:hover a:before {
  content: "▪ News ▪ ";
}

main-categories:first-child:hover a:before {
  content: "▪ Svea Times ▪ ";
}
```

A simplified version using data attributes is below:

```css
/*Adjust main category when child is hovered*/
main-categories:hover a:before {
  content: "▪ News ▪ ";
}

/*USe Data Attribute to adjust hover content*/
main-categories sub-categories a:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-prefix);
}


body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #121212;
}
a {
  color: #121212;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #e5633f;
}

nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;

  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #121212;
}

main-categories {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 92%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
main-categories a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #121212;
}
main-categories a:before {
  content: "▪ ";
}
main-categories a:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
main-categories a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #121212;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
main-categories:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

sub-categories {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
sub-categories a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.938em;
  color: #121212;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: left;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #121212;
}
sub-categories a:hover {
  color: #e5633f;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
sub-categories a:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #121212;
}
main-categories:hover sub-categories {
  display: block;
}
sub-categories a:before {
  content: "• ";
}
sub-categories a:hover:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Serif:wght@300;400;500&family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="menu">
  <main-categories><a href="#void">Education</a>
    <sub-categories>
      <a data-prefix="• News • Education • " href="#">Europe</a>
      <a data-prefix="• News • Education • " href="#">Asia</a>
      <a data-prefix="• News • Education • " href="#">Africa</a>
      <a data-prefix="• News • Education • " href="#">Oceania</a>
      <a data-prefix="• News • Education • " href="#">North America</a>
      <a data-prefix="• News • Education • " href="#">South America</a>
    </sub-categories>
  </main-categories>
  <main-categories><a href="#void">Culture</a></main-categories>
</nav>
```

Comment: I also learned today something new thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

With Sibling elements you can use the following selector

```
#a:hover ~ #b {
    content: "▪ the content ▪ ";
}
```

But unless you refactor the html to you'll need to get javascript involved when the elements aren't selectable with css

```
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('hover', )( => { 
    document.getElementById('b').style.content = "▪ the content ▪" })
})
```

disclaimer: just a Gist, not tested code.